# CSS Transition Not Animating in React Component

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

A react component has a button that opens or closes a div by changing its height style property. The div also has a transition style property which should presumably animate the change in height. However, what we see instead is an instantaneous change in height with the transition duration acting as a delay.

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/antshekhter/xh0b8kw3/

#### Component

```js
const Component = () => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (  
    <div>

      <button onClick={() => setOpen(!isOpen)}>Show Content</button>

      <div className="content" style={{ height: isOpen ? "100%" : 0 }}>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};
```

#### CSS

```css
.content {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height ease 0.5s;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

I tried using `position: fixed` and although it works, the result in my real application of this code created a situation where the content passed overtop of some elements below. I want it such that the elements below get "pushed down" as the content expands to its max height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you are using `100%` for the height. When using CSS transitions, the element's height needs to be explicitly defined for the transition to take effect. However, animating the height property from `0` to `100%` is not straightforward because the initial height value is unknown. You can check it again by changing `100%` to `100px`

In your case you need a height of content inside, I suggest create a useRef to read the height of content inside. Something like this

```
  const contentRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const contentElement = contentRef.current;
    if (isOpen) {
      contentElement.style.height = `${contentElement.scrollHeight}px`;
    } else {
      contentElement.style.height = "0";
    }
  }, [isOpen]);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bpq54tco/5/)

Comment: We can remove the useEffect as well. Not required.

Demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/collapsiblesection-8ctmr7

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your transition is that you're setting the height of the div to 100% when it's open, which means it will try to fill up the whole space of its parent element. But the parent element doesn't have a fixed height, so the browser can't figure out how to smoothly change the height from 0 to 100%. That's why the div just snaps open and closed instead of sliding.

A possible fix is to give the div a specific height when it's open, like 100px or 10em. Then the browser can animate the height from 0 to that value. For example:

```
<div className="content" style={{ height: isOpen ? "100px" : 0 }}>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you not to set height. change the class name. transition act based on css.

```
<div>
  <div onClick={() => setIsOpened((prev) => !prev)}>Button</div>
  <div className="content">
     <p className={isOpened ? "active" : ""}>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.content > p {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-style: solid;
  transition: height 1s ease-in;
}

.content > p.active {
  height: 100px;
}
```